# Не могу настроить xdebug + phpstorm + docker

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

Пытаюсь покрестить phpstorm + xdebug + docker. Ендпоинты не срабатывают

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: docker/php
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - mailcatcher
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=192.168.220.13 remote_enable=1 remote_log=/app/xdebug.log idekey=PHPSTORM"
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"
    networks:
      internal:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.220.13


  webpacker:
    image: node:9-alpine
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: /bin/true

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ./docker/nginx/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/vhost.conf
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - internal

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6381:6379"
    networks:
      - internal

  mailcatcher:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher:latest
    ports:
      - 1080:1080
    networks:
      - internal

  db:
    image: mdillon/postgis:10-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres/backups:/var/lib/postgresql/backups
      - ./docker/postgres/init.sh:/app/db/init.sh
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    networks:
      - internal
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DATABASE: az_dev
      POSTGRES_USER: az
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: az#!dev


networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.220.0/28
```

php/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

# Install modules
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        wget \
        git \
        libxml2-dev \
        zbar-tools \
            --no-install-recommends

RUN docker-php-ext-install mcrypt zip intl mbstring pdo_pgsql exif bcmath xmlrpc soap \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && CFLAGS="-I/usr/src/php" docker-php-ext-install xmlreader

RUN pecl install xdebug-2.6.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pear

COPY ./install-composer.sh /
COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY ./www.conf /usr/local/etc/php/

RUN apt-get purge -y g++ \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && sh /install-composer.sh \
    && rm /install-composer.sh

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

VOLUME /root/.composer
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

vhost.conf

```
# frontend
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80 default; ## listen for ipv4
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        image/svg+xml;

    server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;
    root        /app/frontend/web;
    index       index.php;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # uncomment to avoid processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii
    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        gzip_static on;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # deny accessing php files for the /assets directory
    location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~* /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
## PHP-FPM Servers ##
upstream php-fpm {
    server app:9000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В опции `xdebug.remote_host=192.168.220.13` должен быть указан доступный из контейнера адрес локальной машины, на которой запущен phpstorm, а не адрес докер-контейнера.

Если всё корректно с сетью, то иногда помогает перезапуск PhpStorm после любых изменений настроек remote-xdebug listener'а.