# Почему PHPDebug в VScode не видит локальный сайт на Docker

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Развернул сайт на Docker, но не могу сконнектить IDE VSCode c моим PHP сервером.
Посмотрел кучу мануалов, но даже не знаю где посмотреть ошибки от этого соединения.
Debug Colsole пустая

В phpinfo(видно, что Xdebug включен, видны его параметры, 9000 порт и тд)

В моем Dockerfile:

```
pecl install xdebug

RUN echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \

&& echo "xdebug.remote_enable=true" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \

&& echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=true" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

VS CODE

```
{
    // Используйте IntelliSense, чтобы узнать о возможных атрибутах.
    // Наведите указатель мыши, чтобы просмотреть описания существующих атрибутов.
    // Для получения дополнительной информации посетите: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [


        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "hostname": "::"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу настроить xdebug + phpstorm + docker](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959391/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-xdebug-phpstorm-docker)

Answer (score 2):

Вы имели в виду [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/), очевидно, когда писали про PHPDebug. Из заголовка это не очень понятно, можно подумать что речь идет о [Phpdbg](https://php.net/manual/ru/book.phpdbg.php)

Дальше нужно отметить что очень грубо говоря - xdebug шлет на удаленную машину некую информацию по некому протоколу. Удаленная машина в нашем случаея является как раз ваша IDE, а значит наша задача сделать так, чтобы с хоста где крутится у вас PHP на хост с вашей IDE попала нужная информация на определенный порт.

Еще чуть чуть дальше - 
В xdebug есть настройки, в частности вот [`xdebug.remote_host`](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_host) . В силу того что по-умолчанию все идет на порт 9000 , то мы настройки порта не трогаем без необходимости, а вот значение `remote_host` по-умолчанию это `localhost`, обратите на это внимание.

Ну и теперь давайте соберем все воедино.

Когда вы запускаете `Docker` то с точки зрения докер контейнера `localhost` это сам контейнер, т.е. `xdebug` в этом случае пытается отправить данные самому контейнеру (`localhost:9000`) что в нашем случае не верно.
Почему не верно, спросите Вы, а потом что когда вы запускаете контейнер,  то хост, на котором запущен сам `Docker` и соответственно все запущеные контейнеры (а так же на нем находится ваша IDE) с точки зрения контейнеров по-умолчанию будет скорее всего иметь адрес `172.17.0.1` . Этот адрес вам и нужно прописать в `remote_host` настроек `Xdebug` (ну или тот адрес который конкретно у вас ).

Так же меня немного смущает настройка в вашем IDE  `"hostname": "::"`  не ограничивает ли она ваш хост только ipv6 адресами, но скорее всего нет, однако если не заработает то нужно будет и сюда внимание обратить.

Ну в общем в сухом остатке - добавьте/замените `xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1`

p.s. так же есть настройки xdebug.idekey  обратите на нее  тоже внимание.

updt.
[А вот тут собственно уже это обсуждалось.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959391/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-xdebug-phpstorm-docker?rq=1)

Comment: Почему все указывают ip мастера, а если он другой, это получается что предется пересобирать при различных ip или подсовывать конфиг, зачем?

Comment: @Ghost простите, не понятен вопрос.

Comment: xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 - почему вот эту опцию не используют? Из соображений безопасности?

Comment: @Ghost а кто его знает почему. Я не использую потому что для меня очевиден вариант указания хоста. К тому же если есть проброс конфига (а у меня в любом есть конфиг) при изменении применяется лишь перезапустив  контейнер, без пересборки. Открыть возможность дебажить с любого ip ? Ну наверное. Я не пользуюсь.

Comment: уважаемый гуру xdebug может вы и мне поможете) оба вопроса чекнул, но в упор не вижи ошибки у себя

Comment: @ЕгорТрегубенко а у вас не работает ?